# Merging two rows in android studio ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I was wondering if it was possible to merge two rows in a standard ListView together.

For example:

**ROW 1**

---

**ROW 2**

---

**ROW 3**

---

**ROW 4**

*would become:*

**ROW 1, ROW 2**

---

**ROW 3, ROW 4**

Comment: Wouldn't a `GridView` fit your needs?

Comment: no - i'm trying to find ways around splitting a string since i have no clue how to do it. the best way i figured was to assign the string values to different rows of the listview

Comment: if you can merge you adapter source, the rows will me merged

Comment: i have no clue how to do that.
here are the two lines i used to separate the strings to make two rows if this helps you understand my question better:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder rb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: sb is for first row, rb is for second

Comment: One thing at a time. Since you have a ListView, you must have an adapter, right? What are you passing to your adapter? Show your code so far.

Comment: final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchResults);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: You should change the values of your `searchResult` to contain result of the merge (two itens per row) and then you ListView will reflect that

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like discussed in the comments. The source of the `Adapter` must be changed to achieve the desired results the `ListView`.